# Is there still a way to programmatically get the latest version of a TFVC repository in C#, VS2019?

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2019, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-sdk

I'm attempting to build tools in C# to help automate part of the company I work for's build and deployment system. The most recent tool I've been assigned to is something to see if any members of a specific group of files in the TFS version control system have been changed on the server since the last release.

To make sure that there weren't changes on the server that the machine this automation tool is running on simply hasn't found out about yet, I want to be able to perform within C# code something similar to the [`tf vc get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-command?view=azure-devops) command from the command line interface to TFVC. I found several bits of documentation referring to this and similar questions being asked on Stack Overflow about how to do this, but they were all for VS2010 or earlier, and the APIs that they reference are no longer updated on the Microsoft website.

In the more recent versions of Team Foundation Server, is there any way to programmatically invoke something that would perform something similar to the 'Get Latest Version' command from Visual Studio's Source Control Explorer?

[image: Small censored screenshot of Source Control Explorer in TFS]

Comment: I just got into work and tried Shayki's solution (after fixing the typos), but unfortunately I can't find the TfsTeamProjectCollection class, even after installing the Extended Client. I know that it's out of date - says so right on the top of the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff732550(v%3Dvs.120) - but I can't find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This operation does not exist in the Azure DevOps (TFS) Rest API versions, but you can use the old version, it still working with TFS 2018/9. if you install the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ExtendedClient` NuGet it should be there.

An example how to use it:

```
connection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("tfs url"));
connection.Authenticate();
var = versionControl = connection .GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var worksapce = versionControl.GetWorkspace("local-path-of-the-workspace");
// Do the "Get Latest":
workspace.Get();
```

Another option is to use the tf.exe utility and execute it directly from the c# code like each `.exe` file, for example:

```
string tfPath = "path/to/tf/exe"
string arguments = "vc get ......"
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(tfPath, arguments);
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process p = Process.Start(info);
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I've already added the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ExtendedClient NuGet, but TfsTeamProjectCollection is listed in the documentation as being a part of ```using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client``` and that path is no longer a part of TeamFoundation.ExtendedClient. Where is the class located now?

Comment: Oh ok, so install the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` nuget package.

Comment: I've installed them both:


    ```<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" Version="16.153.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" Version="16.153.0" />```

And I'm still getting

```Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Client' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation' (are you missing an assembly reference?)```

Comment: Do you have `using Mircosoft.TeamFoundation.Client;`?

Comment: That's what's causing the error.

```using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;```

Comment: This works for me with Version 16.153.0 of the extended client. Have you checked that the DLL `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` is in the references of your project?

Comment: One of the things MS changed is the allowed methods of authentication, so the provided solution only works if a user is logged in AND that user has cached credentials for visualstudio.com.  If the cache has timed out, it will prompt for credentials, which is OK if you're running something interactively.  Not so great for automation.